# Index signature's not working when trying to compare values using instanceof

Tags: typescript, lodash

I need to traverse an object and access its properties looking for an array using lodash. I want to check if the key's property is an `instanceof` an `Array`. Consider the following:

```js
const record: MainRecord = {
  id: "10",
  fieldOne: "Foo",
  __typename: "Main",
  related: [
    {
      id: "20",
      fieldTwo: "Bar",
      __typename: "Related"
    },
    {
      id: "21",
      fieldTwo: "Baz",
      __typename: "Related"
    },
  ]
}

// Want to iterate over the keys and check for Array type values
// regardless of what the name of the property is.
_.keys(record).map((key) => {
  console.log(key);

  record["related"] instanceof Array   // No TS compiler error.
  record["id"] instanceof Array        // TS compiler error!
  record["id"] as any instanceof Array // This is actually fine apparently.
  record[key] instanceof Array         // Error! (this is what I'm trying to do)
  record[key] as any instanceof Array  // ALSO an error. Why is this?

  // if(record[key] instanceof Array) {
  //   // ....
  // }      
})
```

When I try to check the `instanceof` `record[key]`, I get the following compiler error:

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'MainRecord'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'MainRecord'.`

Any ideas?

Comment: It might help for an answer if you posted the type definition for `MainRecord`.

Comment: I actually went in a completely different direction with my solution to this problem but the answer provided here checks out (the TS compiles). I guess I was assuming the type definition for `MainRecord` was implied when I defined `record`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript compiler is complaining with `record[key]` that `key` has the type `string` instead of `keyof MainRecord`, probably because the typings of lodash `keys()` method are imprecise, probably as much as the typings of `Object.keys()`.

You should use a type assertion to solve this issue:

```
_.keys(record).map(k => {
  const key = k as keyof MainRecord;
  // if (record[key] instanceof Array) {
  //   // ....
  // }      
})
```